# Passport Local Strategy doesn't get called NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport-local

I have some trouble implementing passport-local on my NodeJS application. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. I'll list the **important code** for this question here.

**app.js**:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

**users.js**:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user.js');

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        console.log('Entered passport'); // This doesn't even happen
        User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (!user) {
                console.log('Unknown User');
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'Unknown User'
                });
            }

            User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (isMatch) {
                    return done(null, user);
                }
                console.log('Invalid Password');
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'Invalid Password'
                });
            });
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/users/login',
    failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password'
}), function(req, res) {
    console.log("Authentication Successfull!");
    req.flash('success', 'You are logged in');
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

**user.js** (Model):

```
module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback) {
    var query = { username: username };
    User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback) {
    User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
        if(err) return callback(err);
        callback(null, isMatch);
    });
}
```

I'm not getting any syntax errors. In users.js I want to log a message to the console, but it doesn't even get there. The post function on the login gets fired when I just enter a function with a console.log there, but now it seems that it doesn't. It just reloads the page (looks like it). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to mount `session` middleware before passport initilized:

```
var session = require('express-session')

app.use(session({ secret: 'xxxxxxx' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: When I use a secret I get a message saying it's deprecated